# Jewish Prophet who could bring fire from the Heaven

Tags: tanach, nevua-prophecy, fire-burning

Was there any Jewish Prophet in the Tanach in which it is said that he was depicted as being able to send down fire from the Heavens? How did this Prophet actually die?

Are there very different narrations about how he died according to the Tanach or is there just only one type of narration about how he died? Or is there no narration at all about how he died? Did he died of old age, did he died of a sickness, or was he killed?

In which book, chapter and verse in the Tanach are these stories narrated?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Tom! We hope you enjoy the site.

Comment: like Elijah? https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15902/jewish/Chapter-18.htm#v=37

Comment: There is a Gemara story about R' Shimon Bar Yochai who learned Torah in a cave for 12 years and when he came out, everything he looked at caught fire but he was not a prophet.

Comment: @ClintEastwood also _Nadav_ and _Avihu_ but I don't know that they were prophets, either, except in the sense that a שפחה על הים was.

Answer (score 11):

**Moses was involved in calling down fire from Heaven during the plague of hail in Egypt.**

Exodus 9:23-24 : (See the entire chapter for more details of the story.)

23. "So Moses stretched forth his staff heavenward, and the L-rd gave forth thunder and hail, and fire came down to the earth, and the L-rd rained down hail upon the land of Egypt."
24. "And there was hail, and fire flaming within the hail, very heavy, the likes of which had never been throughout the entire land of Egypt since it had become a nation."

**Moses and his brother Aharon the Priest, also conducted the inauguration of the Tabernacle Altar in the Wilderness. Their service and that of the people received a response from G-d of fire descending upon the Altar. (See Levit. 9:23-24.)**

23 "And Moses and Aaron went into the Tent of Meeting. Then they came out and blessed the people, and the glory of the L-rd appeared to all the people."

24 "And fire went forth from before the L-rd and consumed the burnt offering and the fats upon the altar, and all the people saw, sang praises, and fell upon their faces."

**Moses' passing is spoken of in Deut. 34: 5-7 He passed away by a special "kiss of G-d" to be taken back to Heaven, and his body was not frail at his passing.**

5. "And Moses, the servant of the L-rd, died there, in the land of Moab, by the mouth of the L-rd."
6. "And He buried him in the valley, in the land of Moab, opposite Beth Pe'or. And no person knows the place of his burial, unto this day."
7. "Moses was one hundred and twenty years old when he died. His eye had not dimmed, nor had he lost his [natural] freshness."

**Aharon passed away in the Wilderness on Mt. Hor. (See Numbers: 20:28) He was rewarded to see his own son take over his position as he passed on.**

28. "Moses then stripped Aaron of his garments and dressed Eleazar his son in them, and Aaron died there on the top of the mountain. [Then] Moses and Eleazar descended from the mountain."

**Elijah the Prophet was granted the miracle of calling fire down from heaven in the Tanach. : I Kings 18: 36-39 (You might read the entire chapter 18.)**

36. "And it was when the evening sacrifice was offered that Elijah the prophet came near and said, "L-rd, the G-d of Abraham, Isaac and Israel, today let it be known that You are G-d in Israel and that I am Your servant, and at Your word have I done all these things."

37 "Answer me, O L-rd, answer me, and this people shall know that You are the 
L-rd G-d, and You have turned their hearts backwards."

38 "And the fire of the L-rd fell and consumed the burnt offerings and the wood and the stones and the earth, and the water which was in the trench it licked up."

39. "And all the people saw and fell on their faces, and they said, "The L-rd is G-d, the L-rd is G-d."

**Also about Elijah, see II Kings 1:12 (You might read the entire chapter.) :**

12 "And Elijah raised his voice and spoke to them, [saying,] "If I am a man of G-d, let a fire come down from heaven and consume you and your fifty men!" And an enormous fire came down from heaven and consumed him and his fifty men."

**Elijah did not experience death as we know it but was taken alive into Heaven.
See II Kings 2:11 (You might read the whole chapter.) :**

11 "And it was that they were going, walking and talking, and behold a fiery chariot and fiery horses, and they separated them both. And Elijah ascended to heaven in a whirlwind."

**King David bought the threshing floor of Arnon the Jebusite in Jerusalem and prayed to G-d for his offerings to be accepted. G-d answered by sending fire down from Heaven to burn the offerings (I Chronicles 21:26)**

26. "And David built an altar there to the Lord, and he offered up burnt offerings and peace offerings, and he called out to the Lord, and He answered him with fire from heaven on the altar of the burnt offerings."

**King David passed away in old age: ( See I kings ch. 1-2) I Kings 1:1 and I Kings 2:10 :**

1:1. "And King David was old, he came into his old age, and they covered him with clothes, but he was not warmed."

2:10 "And David slept with his fathers, and was buried in the city of David."

**King Solomon also prayed at the inauguration of the 1st Temple and G-d responded with fire from Heaven to consume the offerings. (See II Chronicles 7:1)**

7:1 "And when Solomon finished praying, and the fire descended from heaven and consumed the burnt offerings and the sacrifices, and the glory of the L-rd filled the House."

**King Solomon passed away naturally after a 40 year reign. (See I Kings 11: 42-43.)**

42. "The years which Solomon reigned in Jerusalem over all Israel were forty years."
43. "And Solomon slept with his fathers and was buried in the city of David his father; and Rehoboam his son ruled in his place."

Comment: +1, but are there more?

Comment: @msh210 Good q. I don't think there are more prophets who caused fire to descend or were granted that in Tanach. But I do not know it all by heart. :) TY for the vote. :)